# how do I let a user upload .zip files in telerik radeditor

Tags: asp.net-ajax, telerik, radeditor

I'm not sure how to allow my RadEditor to accept .zip files it has all of the default content managers (image, flash, template, media, document) and none of these will allow my users to upload a .zip file and I cannot find where I can change this manually.  I am using Visual Studio 2010 with Telerik and the RadEditor control.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the SearchPatterns property of one of the editor dialogs (e.g. Document Manager) and add the *.zip extension to the list. This way the dialog will allow you to upload/browse zip files. See the telerik online help for the property - [Document Manager](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/documents.html)

Comment: yep this seemed to work I went into the DocumentManager's SearchPatterns property and set it to *.zip now it allows me to add zip files. Thanks.